# How to show image from resources in ListView populated from JSON Response

Tags: android

I'm using some API and get JSON array in response, and I want to add country flag from just a country name.
and the image from drawable.

I have this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Server server = mServers.get(position);
    holder.mFlag.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(server.countryShort));
    holder.mCountry.setText(server.countryLong);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please look on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Server server = mServers.get(position);

    Glide.with(context).load(getImageResourceId(context, server.countryLong)).into(holder.mFlag);

    holder.mCountry.setText(server.countryLong);
}


private int getImageResourceId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the resource directly from resource like this

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(@drawable/myresource.png, null, getPackageName());

imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```